# Sorting in Go lang Interface

Tags: sorting, go, interface

I am using Go. I have a dynamic data creation so I used an interface for adding my data.

```
hives := make([]map[string]interface{}, lenHive)
```

after some operation in this interface I added some data. In this interface some of the data are dynamically adding.

In this interface I have a data like below

```
[
        {
             
       "Career-Business Owner": 0,
            "Career-Entry-level": 0,
            "Dependents-School age children (5-18)": 0,
            "date created": "2021-10-22T13:44:32.655Z",
            "date created": "2021-11-04T05:03:53.805Z",
            "hive_id": 114,
            "name": "Rule test1122-Hive 38",
            "users": 3
        },
        {
            "Career-Business Owner": 0,
            "Career-Entry-level": 0,
            "Dependents-School age children (5-18)": 0,
            "date created": "2021-10-22T13:44:32.655Z",
            "hive_id": 65,
            "name": "Rule hive44555-Hive 8",
            "users": 0
        }
]
```

now I need to sort this data with each field (need to use sorting in each field)

How can I sort filed from interface

here SortBy  is the field (eg Career-Business Owner,Career-Entry-level,date created, hive_id,name,users)

```
 if SortBy != "" {
            if SortOrder == "desc" {
                sort.Slice(hives, func(i, j int) bool {
                    return hives[i][gpi.SortBy] == hives[j][gpi.SortBy]
                })
            } else {
                sort.Slice(hives, func(i, j int) bool {
                    return hives[i][gpi.SortBy] != hives[j][gpi.SortBy]
                })
            }
        }
```

but the sorting is not working properly. What is the method for sorting interface ?

Or any alternative method exist for solving this?

Comment: You can’t sort values by only comparing equality.  The comparator argument is called “less” for a reason.

Comment: Yes.. But if I try using less it will show error   

cannot compare hives[i][gpi.SortBy] < hives[j][gpi.SortBy] (operator < not defined for interface{})

Comment: Yes, you must assert a type and write the comparisons you want.

Comment: @JimB Thank you I got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [func](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#example-Slice) you need to supply to `sort.Slice` should return true if the value at index i is less then the value at index i. So you should replace `==` and `!=` with `<`, or with `>=` for reverse sorting.

Go has no implicit type casing so in your `less` func you will have to check the type of each field with something like a [type switch](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) and handle the comparison based on the type you find.

For example:

```golang
sort.Slice(hives, func(i, j int) bool {
    aInt := hives[i][gpi.SortBy]
    bInt := hives[j][gpi.SortBy]
    switch a := aInt(type) {
    case int:
        if b, ok := bInt.(int); ok {
            return a < b
        }
        panic("can't compare dissimilar types")
        
    case string:
        if b, ok := bInt.(string); ok {
            return a < b
        }
        panic("can't compare dissimilar types")

    default:
        panic("unknown type")

    }
})
```

Comment: in these eg, in struct filed is defined. But I cant define my all fields. They are dynamically creating. Thats why I used this interface

Comment: @MiaMia interface'es are fine. But you can't compare an string and an int. So you need to check what the actual underlying type of your `interface{}` is using the type switch or [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15). Once you have cast both types, you can do a integer comparison, or string comparison or date comparison between the two fields.